# Visual Studio 2013 Attach Database Failure

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, sqldatasource

I am having trouble connecting a .mdf file in my Visual Studio 2013 website project.  For reference, this is the exercise in Chapter 4 of Murach's ASP.NET 4.5 web programming with C# 2012.  The version of VS I am using is 2013 Ultimate.

When I add the SqlDataSource control and attempt to configure the data source, I get the error shown in the image below.  I don't know how to proceed.  Can anyone offer guidance?

Edit: This exercise uses IIS Express which is the default for VS 2012 and 2013.  I was not prompted at any point to enter a server path.

[image: image capture of error message when attaching data source to sqldatasource control]

Comment: Probably the path of your database is not correct.

Comment: check if the service is started